# Collecting Core metrics

Tags: stellar-core

I want to collect core metrics using the /metrics endpoint. However /metrics seems to collect metrics indefinitely, never resetting them. This means that (for example) the "average database.insert.txhistory" metric is over the ENTIRE set of DB insertions, since the core was started. These metrics are useless if I want to the compare the behavior of a certain core against other cores (or even itself) for any window of time. But perhaps I'm using /metrics incorrectly?

I noticed there is a /clearmetrics endpoint - a relatively recent addition (https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/pull/1587). Is this the correct way to clear the metrics? perhaps there's a better way to approach metric collection.

In addition: The docs indicate this /clearmetrics endpoint is for tests purposes. Does this mean it should not be used in production setups?